# What is the difference between cloning the receiver and subscribing to the sender in a tokio watch channel?

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio

When using a tokio watch channel I noticed I can use the subscribe method in the sender to get another receiver or I can clone the existing receiver:

```
let (sender, mut receiver) = watch::channel(1);

let receiver_2 = sender.subscribe();
let receiver_3 = receiver.clone();
```

both receiver_2 and receiver_3 seem to work the same but is there an major difference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `Receiver::clone` and `Sender::subscribe`, there is no difference in the created receiver: they both amount to `Receiver::from_shared (sender.shared.state.load().version(), sender.shared.clone())`.

The only difference is that `Sender::subscribe` will reopen the sender if there were no existing receivers.